# CSS font is not working regardless any change that i made

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hi I know that there are some topic regarding this matter but rest assured i have been looking for solution in those topics but i could not find any solution.

I have tried my best but it still won't get fixed.

So this is my CSS font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'quicksandregular';
    src: url('font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.svg#quicksandregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and here is the body css

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f7f2e2;
    font-family: Quicksand;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

somehow the font is still not show up in my site. It did show up when i have Quicksand font installed in my PC but as soon as i removed the quicksand font, the font switched into a default serif font. This is not what i really wanted since i want other PC to be able to show the font that i used, which is quicksand.

I did check up the font folder is exactly the same in my root folder. By my understanding, the quicksand font should be showing.

The question is, what is my mistake? I would be happy if someone responded to me and reply within 1 day maximum.

Comment: use this : font-family: 'quicksandregular';

Comment: @LaljiTadhani no, it is still not working.. :-( what u meant was to change the name in body right? if it is, it still not working

Comment: problem to root folder

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani hi, do you mean i have a wrong naming for my file and folder?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani looking at your suggestion, do you think i should use import method?
Like this:
import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to put '' and your font inside that. As this is how it is being generated in the css.

Example:

```
font-family: 'quicksandregular';
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Hi @BryanLabuschagne thanks your help but i am afraid that code doesn't work. I really appreciate if you can have a peek inside my root folder and see for a glance for my error.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qbavgvsxicltwx4/AACGEXVeeFO9Otz8sWZ6DK6La?dl=0

Once again, thank you

Comment: Change your @font-face to be like this. (you will see the double dot dash before font)

    font-family: 'quicksandregular';
    src: url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

Comment: Hi @BryanLabuschagne i have done what you suggested me to do, but unfortunately nothing's changed.

src: url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/quiksand2/quicksand-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

Please do advise me again
Thank you

Comment: Hi @Vivorico i have done that and it did work as i downloaded the files. What i will do is put it up on a different link for you to download.

Comment: Okay i have fixed it for you by doing what i said above please check it out **bold**https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u7enlvwkrna0ob1/AABcmLLMUY_vqO99aGwCsS_ua?dl=0**bold**

Comment: Thanks @BryanLabuschagne ! I will look look forward to and give my findings.

Comment: Hi Bryan @Bryan Labuschagne
thank you. It did work. But i hardly touch stackoverflow honestly (will only do when I am stuck)
turns out, your recommendation is right. I just need to change my font-family to quicksandregular and it actually works without the apostrophe.
The next thing is, do you have any other communication platform? (such as email) I want to ask you simple question on how to position my nav on the center. Thanks

Comment: Good to here its working yeah my email is bryanlabuschagne@gmail.com. regards bryan

Answer (score 0):

Everthing is fine but you need to change is the css that is applied

and here is the body css

```
body {
font-size: 12px;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin:0;
background-color: #f7f2e2;
font-family: quicksandregular;
letter-spacing: -1px;
overflow:auto;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Hi Moin, thanks for your reply, but i am afraid it remain the same. Do you mind having a look for my root folder? It should be uploaded anytime soon.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following change to your code it will work.

```
font-family: quicksandregular;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `@font-face`, you have declared the `font-family` property to `quicksandregular`.  Hence, you have to use `font-family: 'quicksandregular'` or `font-family: quicksandregular` in your CSS code.

Also, a good thing to do would be to rename the `@font-face` to **QuickSand**, and have multiple `QuickSand` font-faces with different `font-weight` properties, because this will allow you to use it in structures like this:

```
.myRegularText {
  font-family: 'QuickSand';
  font-weight: regular;
}
.myBoldText {
  font-family: 'QuickSand';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I can't know weather you have a problem with file path or not, since I cannot see the structure of your server's directory, but we assume the following structure:

```
<root> /
  style/
    main.css
  font/
    quicksand2/
      <font-files>
```

In this case, you will have to use

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'QuickSand';
  src: url('/font/quicksand2/<file-name>');
  // ..
}
```

or

```
@font-face {
  // ...
  src: url('../font/<file-name>');
  // ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello @Victor, i have switched my [font-family: 'quicksandregular'] and [font-family: quicksandregular] even with a capital Q but none of them works. I have spent entire day yesterday figuring out how but none came out.

I do hope that you can have a look in the root folder that i have uploaded to dropbox, and here is the link:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qbavgvsxicltwx4/AACGEXVeeFO9Otz8sWZ6DK6La?dl=0

Thank you

Comment: Ok. I will take a look at it, ad hopefully, I will find out what the problem is